# AngularJS - ngInfiniteScroll - memory leak

Tags: angularjs, free

I use infiniteScroll in my application:

[Infinite Scroll link](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

I use it like this:

```
<div infinite-scroll="vm.loadingPagedProducts()" infinite-scroll-use-document-bottom="true" infinite-scroll-immediate-check="false" infinite-scroll-disabled='vm.loadingProducts' infinite-scroll-distance="0" id="productsId">
```

and it works technically fine. 
My only problem is, every time I scroll to bottom, the store increases:

[image: store-dump]

so if I scroll down a lot of times than my application uses e.g. 3GB of RAM and more.
My question now would be how to solve this, how to give the store free.

Comment: Have you tried to disable ngInfiniteScroll one time? Is the memory leak still present? Which version of ngInfiniteScroll are you using?

Comment: what do you mean with "disable infinize scroll one time"?

Comment: Have you tried to disable ngInfiniteScroll one time? Is the memory leak still present? Which version of ngInfiniteScroll are you using?

Comment: yes, memory leak is not present.

Comment: So why do you think your memory leak is depending on ngInfiniteScroll? Please create a plnkr/fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: memory leak is than not present - sorry!!

Comment: Which version of ngInfiniteScroll are you using

Comment: I use Version 1.0.0

Comment: Any feedback m8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ngInfiniteScroll` versions `1.0.0 > 1.2.x` including a lot of memory leaks and will eat your CPU.

**Please use** `ngInfiniteScroll` version `1.3.0` https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/releases and you will be fine. A couple of performance fixes has been released within this version.

- **[Fiddle example with version 1.3.0](https://jsfiddle.net/rocacjv2/)**
- **[Fiddle example with version 1.2.2](https://jsfiddle.net/p8fdgpa4/)**